# How "\n","\t" adds a new line and tab respectively?

Tags: java, c++, c

In programming languages if I use "\n" it adds a newline character.

Could somebody explain how the "\n" gets translated to a newline and the same for "\t"?

Comment: A bit of [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) would help a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "give", what is the "it" you are referring to? Are you asking how the literal sequence `"\n"` becomes a newline in a string constant?

Comment: This only works withing specific functions like `printf`. Whenever the the function finds a '\' character withing the `format string` (usually the first parameter), it knows that the *next character* is supposed to be a special command, rather than the literal character. Also, **you should pick an answer from the existing ones**, cos some of them do a great job of explaining how the process works. Don't ignore the people who put time into helping you figure something out.

Comment: @mrDudePerson That is completely incorrect. All the recognition and translation you refer to is performed by the compiler, not the function.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I lumped escape characters in with things like '%d'.

Comment: @mrDudePerson You also 'de-lumped' language-wide compiler-provided behaviour as only working 'within specific functions like `printf().`

Comment: @EJP Yes, my statement is completely incorrect, as was pointed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the compiler is reading your program and it sees `backslash something` it knows to 'pretend' it saw something else.  You can imagine that part of the compiler works like this:

```
current_character = getNextCharacter();
if (current_character == BACKSLASH) {
    current_character = getNextCharacter();
    if (current_character == 'n') {
        /*oh, they want a newline */
    } else if (current_character == 't') {
        /* it's a tab they want */
    } else /* ... and so on and so forth */
}
```

Comment: A reference to somebody's imagination?  A curious concept.  Any way, if you want to learn about compilers, this seems to be the book www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we talk about strings inside the language, such as `"Hello,\tWorld\n"`, then it's the compilers job to detect a backslash, and then insert the appropriate character sequence for newline and tab on that machine into the string in the generated executable file.

The code to deal with this in the compiler is fairly complex, because there is a huge amount of OTHER things to bear in mind when parsing the code, but if we simplify it a bit:

```
if (inQuote)   // So inside ' or "
{
   if (currentChar == '\')
   {
       switch(nextChar)
       {
          case 'n':
               InsertNewLine();
               break;
          case 't':
               InsertTab();
               break;
          case 'b':
               InsertBackSpace();
               break;
          ... several more of these ... 
          case '\':          // '\\' outputs one '\'
               InsertBackSlash();
               break;
          default:
               Insert(nextChar);   // Ignore any others.
               break;
       }
   }
}
```

I've cheated and made functions for `InsertXX`, where in reality, it's probably just a `*output++ = 10;` or `*output++ = 9;` [or some defined constant that translates to the same].

Answer (score 1):

The \ character is in many languages an 'escape character'. With that character you can add special non printable characters, such as new line or tab, but also quotes. If you need to use " to delimit a string, you can use \" to print a quote mark within it.

for the windows command prompt, ^ works similar for printing special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows that when it sees \n or \t in a string, it must replace it with something special: a new line or a tab character. This is just convention, that backslash followed by a special character (n,l,t,...) means something special.

The reason for this convention is that it in text editors when writing your program it is not possible to embed true newline and tab characters in strings, so to help the programmer they developed this convention.

Comment: It's a feature of the language (at least when it comes to C and C++), not the library functions.

Comment: @jonathan-potter, you are right. The compiler turns these specials into their ascii values, not the library. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Not ASCII but the compilation's target character set and encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The newline character is an ‘escape sequence’ , so called , because the backslash symbol is considered an escape character - it causes an escape from the normal interpretation of a string , so that the next character is recognised as one having a special meaning. 
For example,

- \n introduces a new line.
- \t introduces a tab.
- \\ inserts a backslash
- \” inserts a double quote.

Comment: If this is a quote, provide a citation. If it isn't, don't use quote  formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler stores strings (`"hello"`) as a collection of characters (`'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'`). And furthermore stores those characters as numbers -- which are then represented as bits, etc.

`\n` represents one character although I used two characters to write it. The translation from a human-readable character to the stored number goes through some standardized system, like ASCII or unicode. In ASCII the newline is represented by the decimal number 10 (see http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66 and so on. Each lowercase letter has its own number distinct from the uppercase one, starting from 97.

The newline is only converted to an actual new line when the character is printed. Whenever a special character like `\n` appears in a `System.out.print()` the program asks the terminal produce the desired output, like e.g. skipping the to next line.

The terminal delegates this further down to the operating system and finally to the graphics card to actually make the pixels move. Each part has its own area of responsibility, and every other part has no understanding of how things are done internally in that area. Just that they can interface with each other and make things happen.

Remember that most computer systems are put together by a large group of people. Very few know every aspect of what goes on behind the scenes. And the beauty of it all is that they don't need to!

Comment: The newline already is a newline from the moment the compiler translates the `\n.` All the stuff about what happens at runtime is determined by the ASCII or Unicode definitions and is of no further concern.